# How to force close polygon to overlap/share the border

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, overlapping-features, borders

I am using a shapefile of Brazilian municipalities, so there should be no gap between the polygons. Unfortunately, there are some:

[image]

It seems to be fine, but a closer look reveal the problem (note the scale, polygons are separated by around 20m from each other)

[image]

This affects the generation of a Spatial Contiguity Matrix, for instance. Polygons 1 and 2 are not considered as neighbors, when they should be.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to check for other gaps? For instance, plotting the country polygon and checking for "holes" inside of it.
- Is there a way to correct this for all the polygons? For instance, forcing polygons that are closer then X meters to share the border.

To download the shapefile on `R`:

```
library(geobr)
cities <- read_municipality(code_muni = "all",  year = 2010)
```

Polygons 1 and 2 are with "code_mn" 1400233 and 1505304, respectively.

Comment: for checking gaps you may add all areas; if they fall short of the area of the country there must be other gaps; you may as well use `sf::st_difference(country, st_union(municipalities))` and these will give you a layer with all gaps. For closing the gaps you may use `st_snap` with `tolerance = 20` (your 20 meters)

Comment: Could buffer solve the problem of closing the gaps as well?

Comment: The buffer process works when you want to dissolve polygons by group; in this case you want to close these borders, so buffering forth and back shouldn't work; let's figure something out

Answer (score 1):

Using [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) and selecting on the option of "snap vertices", and then, in console, writing `clean` without further arguments, you get this `st_difference(contry, cleaned_from_mapshaper)` respect to the `read_country()` file, which would only be at the Caroebe region. So programmatically cleaning it would be writing a process for two cases.

I know it's not R; although there's `rmapshaper` package, but it lacks the `clean` function. This is the best solution which doesn't imply a lot of coding.

[image: st_difference]